# 100Base-T1 to 100Base-TX conversion

Tags: ethernet, conversion

I am trying to convert from Fast Ethernet to Automotive Ethernet (and vice versa). I believe I have verified a solution and if someone can confirm, I would appreciate it.

I believe I can just connect the DP83TD510ERHBR (Fast Ethernet) with the DP83TC812R-Q1 (Automotive Ethernet). If I connect the TX to the RX of the other and vice versa, I believe that should work? I do have some confusion on what I need to do with oscillator clock input. Also, I'm not sure what I need to do with the TX and RX clocks and the interrupt.

Below is currently I think I have to do with the left side eventually leading to an RJ45 connector for Fast Ethernet.
[image: Conversion]

Comment: You can take a look at how NXP has solved this here: https://www.nxp.com/products/interfaces/ethernet-/automotive-ethernet-phy-transceivers/ethernet-media-converter-for-drones-rovers-mobile-robotics-and-automotive:RDDRONE-T1ADAPT?tid=vanRDDRONE-T1ADAPT

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I was hoping to use that solution, but unfortunately it appears the IC as well as the COTS item are out of stock which is why I am trying to find an alternate solution. I also tried other COTS solutions, but theyre too big for the board I plan on interfacing it with.

Comment: I did not mean that you should use exactly that board nor the same IC's. But I'm sure there can be some major inspiration to be taken from their schematic, the basic concepts will be pretty much the same whatever PHY's you are using.